# How to convert Timestamp to Decimal and vice versa

Tags: sql

I want to convert timestamp to decimal or vice versa.
Example, I have timestamp in 10-MAR-15 09.35.25 format and decimal in 20150328.114534 format. I want to convert this timestamp to decimal or visa versa.

Comment: Please add a tag for the specific database you are using.

Comment: Please add more details; like the SQL DB that you are using , the SQL function that you are using etc to get better response

Comment: Can't you have the same timestamp in your two examples? (So we can see how the time part is converted.)

Comment: Have you tried checking the documentation for your database software?   Most databases have date-time functions that make this simple, though tedious.

Answer (score 0):

In ANSI standard SQL, you can do:

```
select (extract(year from col)*100000 +
        extract(month from col)*100 +
        extract(day from col)*1 +
        (extract(hour from col)*3600 + extract(minute from col)*60 + extract(second from col)) / (24.0*60*60)
       )
```

Comment: @jarlh . . . Now that you mention that, I realize that I don't understand the logic for the decimal part of the number.